# Conflicting Functionality with COBOL-language-support extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnucobol

I am trying to add the COBOL-language-support extension in Visual Studio Code.
I am running Visual Studio Code in WSL-Ubuntu, and have already downloaded in gnucobol in Ubuntu. I am trying to add the cobol-language-support extension to Visual Studio Code. However, there is an error with cobol language-support. There is conflicting functionality with cobol-language-support. There are two reasons: contributes conflicting grammar, and contributes language id.
Here is the error message:

```
The extension cobol-language-support from BroadcomMFD has conflicting functionality
 Reason        : contributes conflicting grammar
 Reason        : contributes language id
 Id            : BroadcomMFD.cobol-language-support
 Description   : Autocomplete, highlighting and diagnostics for COBOL code and copybooks.
 Version       : 0.21.0
 Repository    : https://github.com/eclipse/che-che4z-lsp-for-cobol.git
 Bug Reporting : https://github.com/eclipse/che-che4z-lsp-for-cobol/issues
```

Comment: is the question "solved" for you? If yes please accept an answer, otherwise drop a comment on in - and possibly Take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about SO works while earning your first badge.

Answer (score 1):

The extension `bitlang.cobol` tells you that you have another extension `BroadcomMFD.cobol-language-support` that has the same features registered for the COBOL language identifier - it isn't reasonable to have two extensions with the same features, so deactivate one and setup the other, then test the features, then do the same with the other and uninstall the extension you don't find reasonable.

For use with GnuCOBOL both `bitlang.cobol` and `bitlang.gnucobol` showed to be working quite good (the later has less features for COBOL in general but is actually targeting GnuCOBOL).